# Map and lambda function return map object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.4.3 . I have list of dict with following structure

```
test['content'] = [
{
"time_cre" : datetimeobject,
"name": "Sam",
"num": 123
},
{
"time_cre" : datetimeobject,
"name": "Sunil",
"num": 124
}
```

I use map and lambda function to convert datetime object to string. My code is

```
map((lambda x:x.update({'time_cre': x['time_cre'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})),test['content'])
```

The above method does not reflect anything.

```
test['new'] = map((lambda x:x.update({'time_cre': x['time_cre'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})),test['content'])
```

The above method works but the result is

```
{
'content':{
"time_cre" : "2017-06-03",
"name": "Sam",
"num": 123
},
{
"time_cre" : "2017-06-03",
"name": "Sunil",
"num": 124
}
],
'new': <map object at 0x7f70e1fe4208>
}
```

So why its is not working in first method and why working in second method. Can anybody explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "The above method does not reflect anything" and later "The above method works"? Explain that, and please also show the expected and actual outputs, plus any tracebacks.

Comment: In first method it returns same dict without anychange

Comment: In Python3.x function like map, filter, reduct will only generate something like generator, which is not like Python2.X, you can convert the generator by list() function, to force execute the generators.

Comment: `list(map((lambda x:x.update({'time_cre': x['time_cre'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})),test['content']))` This works fine . Thank You @MenglongLi